# Multiple horizontally aligned subfigures

Tags: captions, subcaption, subplot

I am having a little bit of trouble trying to display multiple figures aligned horizontally in a same row, I am using the following LaTeX commands, and I obtain the following misplaced figure:

[image: Bad Figure]

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.125\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Boxplot_Profit_RandCA_Library_KPI_19_31181_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.125\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Boxplot_Weight_RandCA_Library_KPI_19_31181_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.125\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Boxplot_Profit_RandCA_Library_KPI_40_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:f}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[d]{0.125\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Boxplot_Weight_RandCA_Library_KPI_40_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[e]{0.125\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Boxplot_Profit_RandCA_Library_KPI_60_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[f]{0.125\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Boxplot_Weight_RandCA_Library_KPI_40_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
       \caption{Six simple graphs}
       \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Your positioning parameters look strange. I know `[b]` and `[c]`, but which package provides `[a]`, `[d]`, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you looking for the following:

[image]

As mentioned @Miyase in his comment, you misunderstand meaning of subfigure options. Thea are itendent for its placement: `t` (for top), `c` (for middle) and `b` (for bottom). Caption labels are defined by `\caption` command and default are small alphabetic letter a, b, c, etc. resetted at each `figure` (or `table`) float.

So, the MWE for your figure should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Boxplot_Profit_RandCA_Library_KPI_19_31181_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Boxplot_Weight_RandCA_Library_KPI_19_31181_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Boxplot_Profit_RandCA_Library_KPI_40_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:f}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Boxplot_Weight_RandCA_Library_KPI_40_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Boxplot_Profit_RandCA_Library_KPI_60_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Boxplot_Weight_RandCA_Library_KPI_40_100000_Rules_8_Size_3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Six simple graphs}
\label{fig:three graphs}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the first parameter of `subcaptionbox` as empty if you dont't need subcaption, such as `\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{a1\label{a1}}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a2\label{a2}}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a3\label{a3}}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a4\label{a4}}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a5\label{a5}}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{a6\label{a6}}{\includegraphics[width=.125\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{bbb}
\label{bbb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]